# Can't connect to EC2 instance - key decryption failure

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, passwords, private-key

I created a 64-bit Windows 2012 server instance on EC2. To connect to it, EC2 asks for me to "Get Password". So, I locate the .pem file on my hard drive and it auto-fills the private key into the box. When I go to press the "Decrypt Password" button, I get an error message: "Error decrypting your password". I've tried it in Firefox, Chrome and Explorer, to no avail. Can someone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue now. I can't provide a solution, but I'll tell what happened.

I've used my company notebook (Win 7) that has many security measures (encrypted drive, anti-virus, etc.). I don't know why, but apparently, the downloaded file is modified by this machine (maybe the file enconding?). I just know that I've tried 5 different times (creating new machines and new keypairs) and it always failed.

As soon as I've tried the same procedure (new machine with new keypair) with my personal desktop (Win 10), it worked instantly as it always do.

I've tried again with my company notebook and it failed again.

So, all I can say is: try using a different machine. Your current machine may be corrupting the .pem file.